# Where’s the control center on iPhone X?

Tags: ios, iphone

I got my iPhone X today, but one thing I’m really perturbed by is there’s no control center! How do I get it back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Control Centre is still there, but you need to **swipe down from the top right of the screen**, not swipe up from the bottom of the screen.

The primary reason for this change is that you need to swipe up from the bottom for unlocking the phone with Face ID, so also opening Control Centre in this way would be problematic. Swiping up is also used to return to the Home Screen as well.

Comment: thankx for ur answer. yeh, I worked it out. :] but why is my question -1?

Comment: Well, to be honest, I almost downvoted your question as well. Basically, the community likes questions that show at least some sort of research or attempt at solving the problem and, in your case, all you needed to do was go to Settings > Control Centre and you would have seen at the top of the screen instructions telling you to swipe down from the top right of the screen. Regardless though, we welcome you to the site and hope you come to find it a valuable resource. You may want to check out the [Help](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help) pages. Oh, I'm glad you got it sorted too! :)